# Set layout for pictures in Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac

Tags: ms-office

I'm working in a huge text-box in Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac.

When I insert a figure I can't find settings for the layout in order to fit the figure in between the text of the textbox. Therefore if I add a new line/word/sentence in the text I have to replace all the figures and the content.

Is there a possibility to merge and fit the picture in the text?

Comment: At the moment I'm not at a system with PowerPoint on it so I have to ask when you say "When I insert a figure", what exactly is "a figure"?

Comment: An image or picture from the tool: insert image from file.